# Redux not saving state

Tags: reactjs, redux

A simple one for those with more Redux experience than I. I'm pulling in some local JSON data and Redux doesn't appear to be adding it to the state. Console logging an array in the data yields 'undefined'.

INDEX.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './components/store/store'
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store()}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

APP.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux' // new import, see below
import { addDataAction } from './components/actions/addDataAction'

etc...

// these cannot be const otherwise an error occurs
let mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.actions.addDataAction() // calling addData on mounting
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <div className="wrapper"> 
            <Header />
            <main>
              {console.log(this.props.data.tshirts)}
            </main>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }

  mapStateToProps = state => ({
    data: state.data 
  })

  mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      actions: bindActionCreators({
      addDataAction
    }, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

REDUCER - addDataReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  data: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_JSON_DATA":
      return {
        ...state, // returning state
        data: action.data // updating the data
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

STORE - store.js

```
import { createStore } from "redux"
import addDataReducer from "../reducers/addDataReducer"

function store() {
  return createStore(addDataReducer)
}

export default store
```

Installed dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0"
  }
```

JSON:

```
{
  "tshirts" : [
    {
      "id": 707860,
      "brand": "H&M",
      "name": "T-Shirt",
      "photo": "tshirt.jpg",
      "colors": [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "gray"
      ],
      "sizes": [
        "S",
        "M",
        "L",
        "XL"
      ],
      "price": 14,
      "currency": "GBP"
    },
    {
      "id": 43455,
      "brand": "Topman",
      "name": "The Tee Shirt",
      "photo": "tshirt.jpg",
      "colors": [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "gray"
      ],
      "sizes": [
        "S",
        "M",
        "L",
        "XL"
      ],
      "price": 14,
      "currency": "GBP"
    }
  ],
  "jumpers" : [
    {
      "id": 653655,
      "brand": "H&M",
      "name": "The J Jumper",
      "photo": "jumper.jpg",
      "colors": [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "gray"
      ],
      "sizes": [
        "S",
        "M",
        "L",
        "XL"
      ],
      "price": 24,
      "currency": "GBP"
    },
    {
      "id": 43455,
      "brand": "Topman",
      "name": "Une Jupe",
      "photo": "jumper.jpg",
      "colors": [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "gray"
      ],
      "sizes": [
        "S",
        "M",
        "L",
        "XL"
      ],
      "price": 23,
      "currency": "GBP"
    }
  ],
  "trousers" : [
    {
      "id": 645645,
      "brand": "Next",
      "name": "The Trow Sir",
      "photo": "trousers.jpg",
      "colors": [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "gray"
      ],
      "sizes": [
        "S",
        "M",
        "L",
        "XL"
      ],
      "price": 24,
      "currency": "GBP"
    },
    {
      "id": 54555,
      "brand": "Topman",
      "name": "Une Trow",
      "photo": "trousers.jpg",
      "colors": [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "gray"
      ],
      "sizes": [
        "S",
        "M",
        "L",
        "XL"
      ],
      "price": 23,
      "currency": "GBP"
    }
  ],
  "jackets" : [
    {
      "id": 44344,
      "brand": "Gap",
      "name": "Gap Jacket",
      "photo": "jacket.jpg",
      "colors": [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "gray"
      ],
      "sizes": [
        "S",
        "M",
        "L",
        "XL"
      ],
      "price": 24,
      "currency": "GBP"
    },
    {
      "id": 422542,
      "brand": "Gap",
      "name": "Their other jacket",
      "photo": "jacket.jpg",
      "colors": [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "gray"
      ],
      "sizes": [
        "S",
        "M",
        "L",
        "XL"
      ],
      "price": 23,
      "currency": "GBP"
    }
  ],
  "suits" : [
    {
      "id": 44344,
      "brand": "Moss Bros",
      "name": "The Three Piece",
      "photo": "suit.jpeg",
      "colors": [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "gray"
      ],
      "sizes": [
        "S",
        "M",
        "L",
        "XL"
      ],
      "price": 24,
      "currency": "GBP"
    },
    {
      "id": 422542,
      "brand": "Gap",
      "name": "The Two Piece",
      "photo": "suit.jpeg",
      "colors": [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "gray"
      ],
      "sizes": [
        "S",
        "M",
        "L",
        "XL"
      ],
      "price": 23,
      "currency": "GBP"
    }
  ]
}
```

Blah blah blah - Stackoverflow says I should add more text.

Answer (score 0):

The dispatch function expects an object as an argument and you're passing it a function.

You need to dispatch the call of the action, not the action creator itself (replace `dispatch(addDataAction)` with `dispatch(addDataAction())`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
 addDataAction: () => dispatch(addDataAction())
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately the tshirt prop is still undefined ;(

Answer (score 0):

**REDUCER - addDataReducer.js**

Provide a initial state for reducer:

```
const initialState = {
 data: []
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_JSON_DATA':
      return {
        ...state, // returning state
        data: action.data // updating the data
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**ACTION - addDataAction.js**

```
import clothesData from '../json/clothes.data.json'

    export const addDataAction = () => { // transformed into a function
      return {
      type: 'ADD_JSON_DATA',
      data: clothesData
     }
   }
```

**STORE - store.js**

```
import { createStore } from "redux"
import addDataReducer from "../reducers/addDataReducer"

function store() {
  return createStore(addDataReducer)
}

export default store
```

**APP.JS**

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux' // new import, see below
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
    import { addDataAction } from './components/actions/addDataAction'


    class App extends Component {

      componentDidMount(){
        this.props.actions.addDataAction() // calling addData on mounting
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <div className="App">
              <div className="wrapper"> 
                <Header />
                <main>
                  {console.log(this.props.data.tshirts)}
                </main>
              </div>
              <Footer />
            </div>
          </Router>
        )
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      data: state.data 
    })

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
       return {
         actions: bindActionCreators({
         addDataAction
       }, dispatch)
    }
}

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added your changes but get unexpected token error with the default in the export statement. I also have to declare functions vars as global lets to get past an error with const. I don't like Redux ;/

Comment: export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)

Comment: Oh! My mistake, this is the "App.js" file. Did you create the store?

Comment: I've updated the code snippets with what I've got. Error is "Parsing error: Unexpected token" <--- this lands on the 'default' of the export statement

Comment: The store is created in store.js / createStore, right?